# Node.js heapdump package is failing while running in container

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, node-gyp, node-heapdump

I am trying to install heapdump package(https://www.npmjs.com/package/heapdump) in my node code base to get the memory usage details. While building the docker image using mhart/alpine-node:14, image is getting built but container is not getting started with below error.

```
{"severity":"error","time":1660281464875,"pid":7,"hostname":"1fefc680cf00","stack":"Error: Error relocating /app/node_modules/heapdump/build/Release/addon.node: _ZN2v812HeapProfiler16TakeHeapSnapshotEPNS_15ActivityControlEPNS0_18ObjectNameResolverEb: symbol not found\n    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1057:18)\n    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)\n    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)\n    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)\n    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)\n    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/heapdump/index.js:16:15)\n    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)\n    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)\n    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)\n    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)","type":"Error","message":"Error relocating /app/node_modules/heapdump/build/Release/addon.node: _ZN2v812HeapProfiler16TakeHeapSnapshotEPNS_15ActivityControlEPNS0_18ObjectNameResolverEb: symbol not found"
```

First I thought this error is because of node-gyp rebuild due to python missing and added the below commands in docker file.

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node:14 as builder

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

ARG NPM_USERNAME
ARG NPM_TOKEN

# Add python packages
# hadolint ignore=DL4006

# RUN which python

# Upstream bug with hadolint ordering
# hadolint ignore=DL4006
RUN apk add --no-cache binutils=2.33.1-r1 && \
    echo "$NPM_USERNAME:$NPM_TOKEN" > /tmp/auth && \
    npm config set update-notifier false && \
    # hadolint ignore=DL4006
    apk add --update python3 make g++\
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*\
    && python3 --version\
    && which python3\
    && npm config set python "/usr/bin/python3"\
    && npm ci --no-audit --production\
    && strip /usr/bin/node


FROM alpine:3.12
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /usr/bin/node /usr/bin/
COPY --from=builder /usr/lib/libgcc* /usr/lib/libstdc* /usr/lib/
COPY --from=builder /app /app
#COPY --from=builder /app/node_modules /app/node_modules

RUN apk add --no-cache tini=0.19.0-r0
RUN apk add --no-cache curl=7.79.1-r1
RUN apk add --no-cache npm=12.22.12-r0

ENV PORT=4444 \
    NODE_ENV=production \
    MAX_EVENT_LOOP_DELAY=1000 \
    MAX_RSS_BYTES=0 \
    MAX_HEAP_USED_BYTES=0 \
    MAX_AGE=86400

EXPOSE $PORT

# an init entrypoint that simplifies signal handling
ENTRYPOINT ["tini", "--"]

CMD ["sh","-c","node src/index.js"]
```

This is installing python without any issues and giving output like

```
#13 24.48 Python 3.8.10
#13 24.48 /usr/bin/python3
```

Along with this while rebuilding I am getting a waring like

```
#13 38.55 > heapdump@0.3.15 install /app/node_modules/heapdump
#13 38.55 > node-gyp rebuild
#13 38.55
#13 58.52 make: Entering directory '/app/node_modules/heapdump/build'
#13 58.52   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/addon/src/heapdump.o
#13 59.12 In file included from ../src/heapdump.cc:15:
#13 59.12 /root/.cache/node-gyp/14.17.3/include/node/node.h:758:43: warning: cast between incompatible function types from 'void (*)(Nan::ADDON_REGISTER_FUNCTION_ARGS_TYPE)' {aka 'void (*)(v8::Local<v8::Object>)'} to 'node::addon_register_func' {aka 'void (*)(v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, void*)'} [-Wcast-function-type]
#13 59.12   758 |       (node::addon_register_func) (regfunc),                          \
#13 59.12       |                                           ^
#13 59.12 /root/.cache/node-gyp/14.17.3/include/node/node.h:792:3: note: in expansion of macro 'NODE_MODULE_X'
#13 59.12   792 |   NODE_MODULE_X(modname, regfunc, NULL, 0)  // NOLINT (readability/null_usage)
#13 59.12       |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
#13 59.12 ../src/heapdump.cc:136:1: note: in expansion of macro 'NODE_MODULE'
#13 59.12   136 | NODE_MODULE(addon, Initialize)
#13 59.12       | ^~~~~~~~~~~
#13 59.37   SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/addon.node
#13 59.40   COPY Release/addon.node
#13 59.40 make: Leaving directory '/app/node_modules/heapdump/build'
```

This is causing the issue i believe

I am using `mhart/alpine-node:14` with below versions

```
node: v14.17.3
npm: v6.14.13
```

Also I am using heapdump of version `0.3.15`

Can someone please help to figure out what is the issue happening here?

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  What's the complete contents of your Dockerfile?  How are you starting the container (maybe via a `docker-compose.yml` file or `docker run` command)?  Do you use any sort of mount to replace the image code with something else?

Comment: @DavidMaze, Thanks for the response. I have included my dockerfile in the question from which the build is happening and container starting in local via a docker build command `docker build -t router-service --progress=plain .`.

Comment: If you read npmjs notes at the end of that module/package page, you see there are some caveats for UNIX and UNIX-like systems.

What I got from that note, is you need double memory size. Does your container image have sufficient memory? If yes then the problem is different I guess.